# How to load a ViewBag in dependency of previous choosen option

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on MVC application. I have a problem with a form in Create View (create.cshtml). The Form has a three select elements (dropdown list). The first one is filled by ViewBag.RodzajePojazdow  which is loaded in 'Create' method in Controller.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.RodzajePojazdow =
        (
            from rodzaj in _context.RodzajPojazdu
            orderby rodzaj.IdRodzaju
            select rodzaj
        ).ToList();
        ViewBag.MarkiSamochodow =
            (
                from markaSam in _context.MarkaSamochodu
                orderby markaSam.IdMarki
                select markaSam
            ).ToList();
        ViewBag.MarkiMotocykli =
            (
                from markaMot in _context.MarkaMotocykla
                orderby markaMot.IdMarki
                select markaMot
            ).ToList();
```

The options in the second select element (second dropdown) should be loaded in dependency of what option was choosen in the first dropdown list. 
The content of the 'ViewBag.MarkiSamochodow'  should be loaded in the second select element (second dropdown) only if in the first select element (e.g) A option was choosen. If in the first select element B option was choosen, the second select element (second dropdown) should be filled by the content of the 'ViewBag.MarkiMotocykli'.

I used Json in CreateMethod to serialize my ViewBags

```
    string jsonMot = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.MarkiMotocykli);
    string jsonSam = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.MarkiSamochodow);
    ViewBag.jsonMarkiMotocykli = jsonMot;
    ViewBag.jsonMarkiSamochodow = jsonSam;
```

Here is a piece of my HTML form:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IdRodzaju" class="control-label" for="wybierzRodzaj">Wybierz rodzaj pojazdu</label>
        <select asp-for="IdRodzaju" class="form-control" id="wybierzRodzaj" onchange="uzupelnijMarki()">
            @{
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.RodzajePojazdow)
                {
                    <option value="@item.IdRodzaju">@item.NazwaRodzaju</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        @*<input asp-for="IdRodzaju" class="form-control" />*@
        <span asp-validation-for="IdRodzaju" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MarkaPojazdu" class="control-label" for="wybierzMarke">Wybierz markę</label>
        <select asp-for="MarkaPojazdu" class="form-control" id="wybierzMarke">
            @*@{
                   --- If A option was choosen in previous select element do this:

                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.MarkiSamochodow)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.IdMarki">@item.NazwaMarki</option>
                        }
                   ---  If B option was choosen in previous select element do this: 

                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.MarkiMotocykli)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.IdMarki">@item.NazwaMarki</option>
                        }
                    }*@
        </select>
```

And then in JS I've tried to load the ViewBag content to the second dropdown list, but the JSON.parse() method doesn't work correctly here

```
<script>
    function uzupelnijMarki() {
        var markiSamochodow = [];
        var markiMotocykli = [];
        var jsonMotocykle = '@ViewBag.jsonMarkiMotocykli';
        var jsonSamochody = '@ViewBag.jsonMarkiSamochodow';
        var markiSamochodow = JSON.parse(jsonSamochody);
        var markiMotocykli = JSON.parse(jsonMotocykle);

        var rodzaj = document.getElementById("wybierzRodzaj");
        //var markisel = document.getElementById("wybierzMarke");
        var seltype = rodzaj.options[rodzaj.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(' napis');
        if (seltype == 1) {
            $("#wybierzMarke").empty();
            markiSamochodow.forEach(function (obj) {
                $('#wybierzMarke').append($('<option></option>').val(obj.NazwaMarki).html(obj.IdMarki))
                });
        }
        if (seltype == 2) {
            $("#wybierzMarke").empty();
            markiMotocykli.forEach(function (obj) {
                $('#wybierzMarke').append($('<option></option>').val(obj.NazwaMarki).html(obj.IdMarki))
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there any easier way to fill the second dropdown in dependency of previous choosen option ?

Thank you,

Comment: go through https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ let me know still if your issue is not resolving.

Comment: Thank you for this article, it helps me a lot. But I don't want to create an extra class only for creating two IList<SelectListItem>. I have Pojazd class. Should I add this two list there ? That class has a few annotation to create a table by migrations. I'm afraid that two list will be added to my Pojazd table in any of future migrations, won't be ?
Otherwise my Create.cshtml View type is Pojazd. I can't add extra IList to my Pojazd class, and I can't create an extra class for this two lists because I can't use two different Model type in .cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. First dropdown is populated by ViewBag.RodzajePojazdow which you are doing good.
2. Now, Intercept change event of First dropwdown via jquery/javascript and make a ajax call to call controller method and pass First dropdown selected value to contoller method method like as below:

Calling javacript function on change event of first dropdown

```
 onChange="PopulateSecondDropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
```

Javascript function to make ajax call to Controller/PopulateSecondDropdown action:

```
    function PopulateSecondDropdown(firstdropdwonvalue) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            url: '/Controller/PopulateSecondDropdown',
            data: { 'firstdropdwonvalue': firstdropdwonvalue },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.length == 0) {
                    alert("no data found.");
                }
                else {                    
                    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                        // bind second dropdwon with result here 
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
};
```

3. Controller method should be look like this. I am not sure about how linq work so , please validate once linq query:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public JsonResult PopulateSecondDropdown (string firstdropdwonvalue)
   {   
      // Use firstdropdwonvalue value to select list for second dropdown   
       return Json((
           from markaSam in _context.MarkaSamochodu
           orderby markaSam.IdMarki
           select markaSam
       ).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```